# dijikstras algorithm for a node with no path

Tags: algorithm, graph

How will the Dijkstra's algorithm work when the shortest path weight are infinity or - infinity( ie if there is no path or no shortest path)?

How will triangular inequality ( d[v] = d[u] + w[u,v]) ) be true? 
I assume v is the target node, u is the parent (here there is no parent) and w is the weight of the edge(uv) which i think is zero.

Comment: You should probably ask it on math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no parent to some node `v`, there is no `u` such that the edge `(u,v)` exists.

Therefore, the step `d[v] = d[u] + w[u,v]` will never take place, and the initial value of `d[v]` (which is set to infinity) will be unchanged until the algorithm halts.

In other words, the triangle inequality `d[v] <= d[u] + w[u,v]` is [vacuous true](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) for all the edges `(u,v)` in the graph.